# Where celery stores task functions?

Tags: django, celery

Have a Django app that runs periodic tasks via celery+kombu+Oracle. I`ve spent some time, until noticed that to change the tasks code celery worker needs to be restarted, not the Django server (uWSGI).

The question is, where does celery stores that code? Some sort of cache or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Celery system consists of 1 or more (usually python) processes which load your methods/tasks in memory.

It's the same as launching an interactive shell. If you do:

```
>>> from spam import eggs
```

`eggs` will be allocated to a memory slot. If you edit `eggs`, you'll have to restart the shell to see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Celery runs several worker processes, separate from the django server process.
These processes load the python code into memory and execute it. They continue running until shut down.
If you update the python code on disk the change will not be picked up by the running processes - you will need to restart them.